# Vertical sticky navigation Menu selects wrong link when going down

Tags: jquery, navigation, scrollto, sticky, jquery-waypoints

I am following this tutorial to build a custom sticky navigation menu with scrolling.

- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints--webdesign-6408

I am using the following jQuery plugins:

- Waypoints: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/
- scrollTo: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

When clicking on the links, the scrolling is working as desired; however; the `.selected` class is not being applied correctly to the menu link when it is clicked and the direction is downwards.

**For example:**

- Menu item 1
- Menu item 2
- Menu item 3

When page loads, `Menu item 1` is highlighted with the `.selected`
   class.

When we click on the `Menu item 2` the scrolling happens but the highlighting does not.

Now, if we click on `Menu item 3` the scrolling happens and the `Menu item 2` is highlighted instead of the `Menu item 3`

**This is the code I am using:**

```
<nav class="section-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><h5><a href="#item-1">item A</a></h5></li>
        <li><h5><a href="#item-2">item B</a></h5></li>
        <li><h5><a href="#item-3">item C</a></h5></li>        
        <li><h5><a href="#item-4">item D</a></h5></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="section-content" id="item-1">some content for this section</div>
<div class="section-content" id="item-2">some content for this section</div>
<div class="section-content" id="item-3">some content for this section</div>
<div class="section-content" id="item-4">some content for this section</div>
```

---

```
jQuery('.section-navigation').waypoint('sticky', {
  offset: 90 // Apply "stuck" when element 30px from top
});

jQuery(function() {
  var sections = jQuery('.section-content');
  var navigation_links = jQuery('nav a');

  sections.waypoint({
    handler: function(event, direction) {
      var active_section;
      active_section = jQuery(this);

      if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();

      var active_link = jQuery('nav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
      navigation_links.closest('li').removeClass("selected");
      active_link.closest('li').addClass("selected");

    },
    offset: '-20px'
  });

   jQuery('nav a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.scrollTo(
      jQuery(this).attr("href"),
      {
        duration: 200,
        //offset: { 'left':0, 'top':-0.15*jQuery(window).height() }
        offset: { 'top':+0.15 }
      }
    );

  }); 
});
```

**I found three more related questions but none of them give an answer to solve my problem:**

- [Waypoints - Sticky Header Navigation. Links Are Highlighted Upon Scrolling Down But Not Scrolling Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998175/waypoints-sticky-header-navigation-links-are-highlighted-upon-scrolling-down)
- [jquery waypoints hilighting navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146797/jquery-waypoints-hilighting-navigation?rq=1)
- [jQuery Waypoints sticky nav when scrolling up via a click is 1px off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824467/jquery-waypoints-sticky-nav-when-scrolling-up-via-a-click-is-1px-off?rq=1)

Please help me on solving this. Thank you.

**EDIT:** Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uteqm28v/2/

Comment: Make JSFiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/  We can help you with quick

Comment: @Prog I just updated the post with the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head to the wall, I finally fixed the code I had. It was very simple fix.

I just had to remove `event` from the handler and set both `offset` to the same number of pixels (they can be opposite, one positive and one negative).

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uteqm28v/5/

And the code:

```
$('.section-navigation').waypoint('sticky', {
  offset: 30 // Apply "stuck" when element 30px from top
});

jQuery(function() {
    var sections = jQuery('.section-content');
    var navigation_links = jQuery('nav a');

  sections.waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {
      var active_section;
      active_section = jQuery(this);

      if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();
      var active_link = jQuery('nav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
      navigation_links.closest('li').removeClass("selected");
      active_link.closest('li').addClass("selected");

    },
    offset: '20px' //this can be negative
  });

   jQuery('nav a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.scrollTo(
      jQuery(this).attr("href"),
      {
        duration: 200,
        //offset: { 'left':0, 'top':-0.15*jQuery(window).height() }
        offset: { 'top':20 }
      }
    );

  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

- Working [JsFiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/uteqm28v/4/)

`

```
$('.section-navigation').waypoint('sticky', {
  offset: 30 // Apply "stuck" when element 30px from top
});
 var previousScroll = 0;
 var  drctn = '';
var linkClk = false;
(function () {    
    $(window).scroll(function () {
       var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
           drctn='down';           
       }
       else {
          drctn='up';          
       }
       previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}());

jQuery(function() {
    var sections = jQuery('.section-content');
    var navigation_links = jQuery('nav a');

  sections.waypoint({
    handler: function(event, direction) {
      var active_section;
      active_section = jQuery(this);    
        if(linkClk){
            linkClk=false;
            if (drctn=='down'){            
               active_section = active_section.next();    
           }
           var  active_link = jQuery('nav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');


      navigation_links.closest('li').removeClass("selected");
      active_link.closest('li').addClass("selected");
        }
        else
            {
                if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();

      var active_link = jQuery('nav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
      navigation_links.closest('li').removeClass("selected");
      active_link.closest('li').addClass("selected");
            }



    },
    offset: '-20px'
  });

   jQuery('nav a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {       
       linkClk = true;
    event.preventDefault();
       //jQuery('nav a').closest('li').removeClass("selected");
       //jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass("selected");
    jQuery.scrollTo(        
      jQuery(this).attr("href"),
      {
        duration: 200,
        //offset: { 'left':0, 'top':-0.15*jQuery(window).height() }
        offset: { 'top':+0.15 }

      }
    );

  }); 
});
```

`

**[Demo JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/uteqm28v/4/)**

Comment: I am sorry to say that it does not quite work. If you go from item 1 to item 4, item 4 does not highlight. I did some modifications to mine and it is working as intended, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/uteqm28v/5/